# How does web3.eth.estimateGas work?

Tags: web3.py, gas-estimate

I have tested two situations using "web3.eth.estimateGas" to estimate the gas cost of contract transaction.

First one is to get contract by the address of a deployed contract and estimate the gas cost:

```
mycontract = w3.eth.contract(address=mycontract_address, abi=mycontract_abi)
tx = printer.functions.fun(
    a, b, c).buildTransaction({
        'from':
        address,
        'value':
        0,
        'gasPrice':
        gasPrice,
        'gas':
        1500000,
        "nonce":
        w3.eth.getTransactionCount(address),
    })
 gasEstimate = w3.eth.estimateGas(tx)
```

The second one is to get contract by the abi and contract bytecode and estimate the gas cost:

```
contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
tx = printer.functions.fun(
    a, b, c).buildTransaction({
        'from':
        address,
        'value':
        0,
        'gasPrice':
        gasPrice,
        'gas':
        1500000,
        "nonce":
        w3.eth.getTransactionCount(address),
    })
 gasEstimate = w3.eth.estimateGas(tx)
```

When the function call can be executed correctly, they both can get the estimated gas cost. However, when I pass in parameters{a,b,c} that will cause failed execution, the first situation gives the following error:

```
gas estimate err: {'code': -32016, 'data': 'Reverted', 'message': 'The execution failed due to an exception.'}
```

but the second gives no errors even the function execution will fail. I wonder why this could happen? How does "web3.eth.estimateGas" work? Any suggestions are welcome!